# What kind of animation is this from BBC?

Tags: css, ajax, authentication

Does anyone here knows what kind of animation has this login screen when typing the day, month and year from BBC? https://account.bbc.com/register?context=music&nonce=4jvMSIbr-vC0lTOQ87ZobFJWu1yG4KAG6NKQ&ptrt=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fmusic%2Fplaylists%2Fp055b5vw&userOrigin=music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like it's a combination of CSS properties `line-height`, `font-size` and `bottom`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is obfuscated, so you couldn't really tell unless you undid it. Here it is in case you don't want to look:

```
!function(e,t,n){function r(e,t){return typeof e===t}function o(){var e,t,n,o,i,s,a;for(var u in b)if(b.hasOwnProperty(u)){if(e=[],t=b[u],t.name&&(e.push(t.name.toLowerCase()),t.options&&t.options.aliases&&t.options.aliases.length))for(n=0;n<t.options.aliases.length;n++)e.push(t.options.aliases[n].toLowerCase());for(o=r(t.fn,"function")?t.fn():t.fn,i=0;i<e.length;i++)s=e[i],a=s.split("."),1===a.length?w[a[0]]=o:(!w[a[0]]||w[a[0]]instanceof Boolean||(w[a[0]]=new Boolean(w[a[0]])),w[a[0]][a[1]]=o),T.push((o?"":"no-")+a.join("-"))}}function i(e){var t=x.className,n=w._config.classPrefix||"";if(S&&(t=t.baseVal),w._config.enableJSClass){var r=new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+n+"no-js(\\s|$)");t=t.replace(r,"$1"+n+"js$2")}w._config.enableClasses&&(t+=" "+n+e.join(" "+n),S?x.className.baseVal=t:x.className=t)}function s(e,t){if("object"==typeof e)for(var n in e)E(e,n)&&s(n,e[n]);else{e=e.toLowerCase();var r=e.split("."),o=w[r[0]];if(2==r.length&&(o=o[r[1]]),"undefined"!=typeof o)return w;t="function"==typeof t?t():t,1==r.length?w[r[0]]=t:(!w[r[0]]||w[r[0]]instanceof Boolean||(w[r[0]]=new Boolean(w[r[0]])),w[r[0]][r[1]]=t),i([(t&&0!=t?"":"no-")+r.join("-")]),w._trigger(e,t)}return w}function a(){return"function"!=typeof t.createElement?t.createElement(arguments[0]):S?t.createElementNS.call(t,"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",arguments[0]):t.createElement.apply(t,arguments)}function u(){var e=t.body;return e||(e=a(S?"svg":"body"),e.fake=!0),e}function l(e,n,r,o){var i,s,l,f,c="modernizr",p=a("div"),d=u();if(parseInt(r,10))for(;r--;)l=a("div"),l.id=o?o[r]:c+(r+1),p.appendChild(l);return i=a("style"),i.type="text/css",i.id="s"+c,(d.fake?d:p).appendChild(i),d.appendChild(p),i.styleSheet?i.styleSheet.cssText=e:i.appendChild(t.createTextNode(e)),p.id=c,d.fake&&(d.style.background="",d.style.overflow="hidden",f=x.style.overflow,x.style.overflow="hidden",x.appendChild(d)),s=n(p,e),d.fake?(d.parentNode.removeChild(d),x.style.overflow=f,x.offsetHeight):p.parentNode.removeChild(p),!!s}function f(e,t){return!!~(""+e).indexOf(t)}function c(e){return e.replace(/([A-Z])/g,function(e,t){return"-"+t.toLowerCase()}).replace(/^ms-/,"-ms-")}function p(t,n,r){var o;if("getComputedStyle"in e){o=getComputedStyle.call(e,t,n);var i=e.console;if(null!==o)r&&(o=o.getPropertyValue(r));else if(i){var s=i.error?"error":"log";i[s].call(i,"getComputedStyle returning null, its possible modernizr test results are inaccurate")}}else o=!n&&t.currentStyle&&t.currentStyle[r];return o}function d(t,r){var o=t.length;if("CSS"in e&&"supports"in e.CSS){for(;o--;)if(e.CSS.supports(c(t[o]),r))return!0;return!1}if("CSSSupportsRule"in e){for(var i=[];o--;)i.push("("+c(t[o])+":"+r+")");return i=i.join(" or "),l("@supports ("+i+") { #modernizr { position: absolute; } }",function(e){return"absolute"==p(e,null,"position")})}return n}function v(e){return e.replace(/([a-z])-([a-z])/g,function(e,t,n){return t+n.toUpperCase()}).replace(/^-/,"")}function m(e,t,o,i){function s(){l&&(delete D.style,delete D.modElem)}if(i=!r(i,"undefined")&&i,!r(o,"undefined")){var u=d(e,o);if(!r(u,"undefined"))return u}for(var l,c,p,m,h,y=["modernizr","tspan","samp"];!D.style&&y.length;)l=!0,D.modElem=a(y.shift()),D.style=D.modElem.style;for(p=e.length,c=0;c<p;c++)if(m=e[c],h=D.style[m],f(m,"-")&&(m=v(m)),D.style[m]!==n){if(i||r(o,"undefined"))return s(),"pfx"!=t||m;try{D.style[m]=o}catch(e){}if(D.style[m]!=h)return s(),"pfx"!=t||m}return s(),!1}function h(e,t){return function(){return e.apply(t,arguments)}}function y(e,t,n){var o;for(var i in e)if(e[i]in t)return n===!1?e[i]:(o=t[e[i]],r(o,"function")?h(o,n||t):o);return!1}function g(e,t,n,o,i){var s=e.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+e.slice(1),a=(e+" "+N.join(s+" ")+s).split(" ");return r(t,"string")||r(t,"undefined")?m(a,t,o,i):(a=(e+" "+M.join(s+" ")+s).split(" "),y(a,t,n))}function C(e,t,r){return g(e,n,n,t,r)}var b=[],_={_version:"3.5.0",_config:{classPrefix:"",enableClasses:!0,enableJSClass:!0,usePrefixes:!0},_q:[],on:function(e,t){var n=this;setTimeout(function(){t(n[e])},0)},addTest:function(e,t,n){b.push({name:e,fn:t,options:n})},addAsyncTest:function(e){b.push({name:null,fn:e})}},w=function(){};w.prototype=_,w=new w;var E,T=[],x=t.documentElement,S="svg"===x.nodeName.toLowerCase();!function(){var e={}.hasOwnProperty;E=r(e,"undefined")||r(e.call,"undefined")?function(e,t){return t in e&&r(e.constructor.prototype[t],"undefined")}:function(t,n){return e.call(t,n)}}(),_._l={},_.on=function(e,t){this._l[e]||(this._l[e]=[]),this._l[e].push(t),w.hasOwnProperty(e)&&setTimeout(function(){w._trigger(e,w[e])},0)},_._trigger=function(e,t){if(this._l[e]){var n=this._l[e];setTimeout(function(){var e,r;for(e=0;e<n.length;e++)(r=n[e])(t)},0),delete this._l[e]}},w._q.push(function(){_.addTest=s});var P=_.testStyles=l,L=function(){function e(e,t){var o;return!!e&&(t&&"string"!=typeof t||(t=a(t||"div")),e="on"+e,o=e in t,!o&&r&&(t.setAttribute||(t=a("div")),t.setAttribute(e,""),o="function"==typeof t[e],t[e]!==n&&(t[e]=n),t.removeAttribute(e)),o)}var r=!("onblur"in t.documentElement);return e}();_.hasEvent=L,w.addTest("oninput",function(){var n,r=a("input");if(r.setAttribute("oninput","return"),L("oninput",x)||"function"==typeof r.oninput)return!0;try{var o=t.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");n=!1;var i=function(e){n=!0,e.preventDefault(),e.stopPropagation()};o.initKeyEvent("keypress",!0,!0,e,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,"e".charCodeAt(0)),x.appendChild(r),r.addEventListener("input",i,!1),r.focus(),r.dispatchEvent(o),r.removeEventListener("input",i,!1),x.removeChild(r)}catch(e){n=!1}return n});var z=a("input"),A="autocomplete autofocus list placeholder max min multiple pattern required step".split(" "),j={};w.input=function(t){for(var n=0,r=t.length;n<r;n++)j[t[n]]=!!(t[n]in z);return j.list&&(j.list=!(!a("datalist")||!e.HTMLDataListElement)),j}(A),w.addTest("target",function(){var t=e.document;if(!("querySelectorAll"in t))return!1;try{return t.querySelectorAll(":target"),!0}catch(e){return!1}});var q=_._config.usePrefixes?" -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- ".split(" "):["",""];_._prefixes=q,w.addTest("touchevents",function(){var n;if("ontouchstart"in e||e.DocumentTouch&&t instanceof DocumentTouch)n=!0;else{var r=["@media (",q.join("touch-enabled),("),"heartz",")","{#modernizr{top:9px;position:absolute}}"].join("");P(r,function(e){n=9===e.offsetTop})}return n});var k="Moz O ms Webkit",N=_._config.usePrefixes?k.split(" "):[];_._cssomPrefixes=N;var B={elem:a("modernizr")};w._q.push(function(){delete B.elem});var D={style:B.elem.style};w._q.unshift(function(){delete D.style});var M=_._config.usePrefixes?k.toLowerCase().split(" "):[];_._domPrefixes=M,_.testAllProps=g,_.testAllProps=C,w.addTest("flexbox",C("flexBasis","1px",!0)),w.addTest("formvalidation",function(){var t=a("form");if(!("checkValidity"in t&&"addEventListener"in t))return!1;if("reportValidity"in t)return!0;var n,r=!1;return w.formvalidationapi=!0,t.addEventListener("submit",function(t){e.opera&&!e.operamini||t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()},!1),t.innerHTML='<input name="modTest" required="required" /><button></button>',P("#modernizr form{position:absolute;top:-99999em}",function(e){e.appendChild(t),n=t.getElementsByTagName("input")[0],n.addEventListener("invalid",function(e){r=!0,e.preventDefault(),e.stopPropagation()},!1),w.formvalidationmessage=!!n.validationMessage,t.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click()}),r}),o(),i(T),delete _.addTest,delete _.addAsyncTest;for(var O=0;O<w._q.length;O++)w._q[O]();e.Modernizr=w}(window,document);
```

Sorry that I can't be of more help. You might be able to use a de-obfuscator (see [JSDetox](http://www.relentless-coding.com/projects/jsdetox/)) in order to help you. Good luck!